# boost::asio::io_service with a bounded and/or priority queue?

Tags: c++, boost

Looking at task_io_service.ipp, seems like io_service uses a FIFO queue behind the scenes to store its tasks. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a good way to use a priority queue with io_service instead of the built-in FIFO?  Ideally, I'm looking for a sneaky way to smuggle a custom task queue into io_service.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sample for that:

#### [Invocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.invocation)

> This example shows how to customise handler invocation. Completion handlers are added to a priority queue rather than executed immediately.
>
> - [boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp)

Comment: Great answer! I do have a follow up question, if that's ok. I want to have a threaded version of this (through boost::thread_group, for example). Does this mean I would then need two mutexes - one for the priority queue, the other used internally by io_service? My performance will suffer, right? Is it possible to do everything with just one mutex? This is how one would code this directly...